# Flutter: AVCapturePhotoOutput' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Since I upgrade Flutter on the stable channel, I can't run on IOS simulators. This is an error that often appears when updating Flutter, only and despite my research I can't find any solutions. I tried to remove Podfile.lock, update pod and reinstall, change channel and upgrade but always the same error.

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-FR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Beginning of log:

```
Xcode build done.                                           12.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET gRPC-Core OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/flo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:62:2
    4: warning: 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer
    [-Wunguarded-availability]
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output
                           ^
    In module 'AVFoundation' imported from
    /Users/flo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.4.3+2/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
    /iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVCaptureP
    hotoOutput.h:48:12: note: 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has been marked as being introduced in iOS
    10.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
    @interface AVCapturePhotoOutput : AVCaptureOutput
```

Answer (score 4):

I share the solution that works for those who need it:

```
rm -rf ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

Comment: I had the same issue after switch back to the master branch, still get the errors after executed the command you provided.

Comment: @HaifengZhang I moved to stable channel (v1.17.0). I think you already execute flutter clean, try to Clean Build Folder on Xcode - remove the cache from your flutter source folder